# I have a Map<Coordinates , Markers> on java/andrdoid. Given a Coordinate, is there a way to return Markers within a radius

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I have a Map on java/andrdoid. Given a Coordinate, is there a way to return all Markers within a radius.

I parse a KML file and get coordinates in string format and turn them into

```
NavigableMap<double[], Marker> map = new TreeMap();
double[] coordinates = ... 
Marker m = ...
map.put(coordinates, googleMap.addMarker(m));
```

and eventually I'll have a bunch of map with coordinates as keys and markers as values.

but this gives me a

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [D is not Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.find(TreeMap.java:254)
    at java.util.TreeMap.putInternal(TreeMap.java:240)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:186)
```

I'm looking for something like subMap function from NavigableSet to return all Markers, given a point+radius.

I realize I can just have a ArrayList and compare one by one

```
 if(distance(Coordinates ,marker.getCoordinates())<=radius)
        marker.setVisbile(true);
..etc..
```

but my question is, is there such Map or HashMap that returns a subset of that map based on coordinates with radius.

Thank you.

Comment: have you consider to wrap your coordinates into object with implements comparable?

Comment: thanks Darshan for editing

Answer (score 0):

Usually for this type of problem an R-Tree works very well.  The basic data structure is described [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree)

There are a few Java implementations out there, have a look at [java spatial index](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsi/) or [this one](https://github.com/davidmoten/rtree)